# How to use group by statement on multiple fields in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**I have the following tables:**

1. **StudentProfile** in which I have fields `RollNumber`, `Major`
2. **StudentEnrollment** in which I have fields `RollNumber`, `CourseCode`, `Section`,  `Semester`
3. **DepartmentFees** in which I have fields `DepartmentName`, `Semester`, `Fees`

What I'm trying to do it to find the fees a student has to pay in a particular semester. The problem is the **StudentEnrollment** table has multiple repeated values which is making it difficult to find the exact fees.

My **StudentEnrollment** table is like this:

```
RollNO     |CourseCode     |Section     |Semester
-----------+---------------+------------+------------
ST-0001    |BIOL 300       |A           |Fall   2018
ST-0001    |BIOL 500       |A           |Spring 2018
ST-0001    |BIOL 450       |B           |Spring 2018
ST-0001    |BIOL 475       |A           |Spring 2018
ST-0002    |CHEM 500       |A           |Spring 2018
ST-0002    |CHEM 450       |B           |Spring 2019
```

Now with repeated values of roll number and Semester how do I get the correct answer.
If I use `GROUP BY (StudentEnrollment.RollNo)` , the roll number does not repeat I cant get all the semesters the student has attended and if I use `GROUP BY (StudentEnrollment.RollNo)` I dont get all the student's rollnumbers in the semsester.

Initially I tried using

```
Select 
    a.RollNo, 
    b.Semester, 
    c.Fees
FROM StudentProfile         a
LEFT JOIN StudentEnrollment b ON b.RollNo = c.RollNo 
LEFT JOIN DepartmentFees    C ON c.DepartmentName = a.Major //AND maybe join semester?
```

But it doesn't seem to work. What can I try next?

Comment: Looks like you need another common column between departmentFees and enrollment. Is there more table column information you can share (seems you should join on semester)? 

Also, why are you joining department name on major?

Comment: @JairusMartin The Name of the department and Major are the same. Like, ComputerScience, Biology, Chemistry etc.

Comment: Okay, does it make sense to also join those two tables on semester as well?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: Sample table data should be given for all tables, and also the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the columns to the Group by clause:

```
Select 
    a.RollNo, 
    b.Semester, 
    sum(c.Fees) AS 'total'

FROM StudentProfile         a
LEFT JOIN StudentEnrollment b ON b.RollNo = c.RollNo 
LEFT JOIN DepartmentFees    C ON c.DepartmentName = a.Major //AND maybe join semester?
GROUP BY 
    a.RollNo, 
    b.Semester
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mention b.Semester, c.Fees in select statement, so to do group by RollNo and Semester, add a.RollNo and b.Semester in GROUP BY clause, I have used "JOIN" instead of "LEFT JOIN" cause use JOIN/INNER JOIN when you want to return only records having pair on both sides, and you’ll use LEFT JOIN when you need all records from the “left” table, no matter if they have pair in the “right” table or not.

```
Select 
    a.RollNo, 
    b.Semester, 
    sum(c.Fees) AS 'total'

FROM StudentProfile         a
JOIN StudentEnrollment b ON b.RollNo = c.RollNo 
JOIN DepartmentFees    C ON c.DepartmentName = a.Major
GROUP BY 
    a.RollNo, 
    b.Semester
```

Comment: I explicitly used `LEFT JOIN` since this person is a beginner SQL user and JOIN will hide any useful mistakes made.  Rather than copying an answer and alter it slightly makes more sense just to comment on the answer already provided.